# Jsoup does not retrieve first part of HTML document

Tags: html, jsoup, vimeo

I'd like to extract and print the HTML of a [Vimeo page](https://vimeo.com/categories/food/cooking/videos) with Jsoup, but only the **second part** of the HTML is retrieved.
I already tried to set `.maxBodySize(0)` but nothing changes; this is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class PrintVimeoHTML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vimeo.com/categories/food/cooking/videos")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
            .maxBodySize(0)
            .timeout(600000)
            .get();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

And what is extracted starts from [this highlighted `<script>` tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qON0.png).
What should I do to extract the `<div>` that precedes the script?

Comment: Might be js related, so use some headless browser with js support. htmlunit might work.

Comment: @FredericKlein you mean that I should use htmlunit instead of jsoup?

Comment: Worth a try. Other alternatives: selenium, phantomjs, etc.

Comment: Thanks @FredericKlein , I tried Selenium and it does what I needed.It was really that Jsoup does not run JS.

Comment: Please consider writing (and accepting) an answer yourself for others with a similar problem and to avoid cluttering stackoverflow with unresolved questions (or remove this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Selenium instead of Jsoup. It was a JavaScript issue: Jsoup does not run JavaScript, and my content was actually loaded by a script.
Selenium is good for this purpose because it simulates a real browser, so it can get the whole HTML generated.